# Please clarify values for STM32 SYSCFG_EXTICR registers

Tags: stm32, interrupt

The following is an excerpt from the [STM32F0x1 reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031936-stm32f0x1-stm32f0x2-stm32f0x8-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf):

[image]

There are a lot of `x`'s in play here. They all seem to be referring to the external interrupt number (i.e. EXTI**x**), but what is the `x` circled in red? It's a part of the binary number, so it is either 0 or 1, not the interrupt number or pin number. The documentation mentions nothing about what it means when it's 0 and when it's 1. If I dig through the header files, it seems this `x` is always zero.

Is the documentation just incomplete, or did I miss something or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation states that the meaning of the x-bit (the left-most bit) is reserved - i.e. it has no documented meaning for the time being.

As you indicate that the header-files always leave it as 0, this is what you want to use yourself.

It is usually documented this way because a new variant of the MCU might be offered later with a different configuration (i.e. other peripherals or similar) - and in those configurations the bit could then be documented to have a distinct meaning.